# Android device not recognised by eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have been developing an app for some time on a laptop machine and it has been going well. I always run the application on my own device just fine.

However, today I wanted to start working on the device from a different computer. So I downloaded the android SDK and tried to run the application on the same device (same phone, different computer).

The phone device has not changed and the android manifest has not changed. However, on the new computer, my phone is simply not being recognized by eclipse. It is being recognized by windows just fine, it is in developer mode and everything.

My minimum target SDK is 11 and my maximum is 17. When I try and find a device in eclipse, it says:

`[2013-10-02 13:29:22 - Jelly] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.3'.`

The only difference is that the new computer (doesn't recognise the device) is running the `Android SDK 2013-09-17` and the older computer (the one where it works) is running `Android SDK 2013-05-22`.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a windows machine? Don't you have to install the driver then?

Comment: Yeah, its a windows machine. The device is recognized by windows just fine on both machines. It is eclipse that does not recognize it :(

Comment: You _do_ need to install the adb usb driver though..

Comment: I think remember that I had to install the driver anyway. But I'm not sure because I'm not using windows for over a year now.

Comment: Forget Eclipse for debugging connection problems, use the shell. Eclipse just displays what `adb` found.

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct `driver` for that device is installed in your new machine or not and if it is installed then kill the `adb` from the `TaskManager` it will connect it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **trusted** Wi-Fi connection nearby you can use adb over network to connect without a cable. There are apps in the play store for that. Search for "adb Wi-Fi".

Comment: only for rooted devices

Comment: @Vinay I would say it's almost a rule of thumb for a developer to root the device. If need arises, it can be unrooted easily at any time. Unless you are worried about warranty, there's almost no reason not to root.

Comment: i dont think the number of the developers who root their devices is greater than the number of those who dont. Even if they were, its worth mentioning anyway.